# Asynchronous error handling in MVC 5 filters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I've made a custom filter attribute extending the `HandleErrorAttribute`, that catches all exceptions.

My entire application is built around async architechture, throughout the stack.
This means, that I somehow have to use the `OnException(ExceptionContext contect)` override asynchronously. Something like this, would be how I imagined it (Simplified for readability):

```
public async override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
{
    base.OnException(context);
    var logId = await LogException(e, httpContext); //LogException calls an async method and returns the ID of the exception, after it has been saved to the database. I this ID in the filterContext, which is why I need the result of the method
}
```

However, this would result in `InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle`.

I cannot simply call .Result on the task when called synchronously, as this would cause deadlocks.

So I guess my question is: How do I create a filter in MVC5, that can log errors asynchronously?

Comment: You should be able to use the standard `override` without the `async` and `await` keywords. They should still be valid despite your app being written using `async`, that should not matter. The `HandleErrorAttribute.OnException` should still get hit as you'd expect.

Comment: @DavidPine I cannot use the await keyword without adding async to the method. And without the await keyword, I cannot safely get the return value of LogException method without risking a deadlock

Comment: Ah, I see. Why does `LogException` need to be `async`?

Comment: Well. I guess it doesn't, on the same level that no method really needs to be async. But it ensures the best possible use of the server's ressources, and I would be kinda sad to make a set of synchronous interfaces, just to cover this particular use case.

Comment: I would hope that this logging code isn't used a lot, if it is you have bigger issues to worried about. Even though it is I/O bound assuming you're writing logs to disk -- throughput is only a concern if you have a ton of requests that are all failing. My point being, for error logging it might be ok to have them write synchronous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since error handling usually is not hot code there are no performance concerns here. Therefore, do what's most convenient to you.

For example, you can block on the task returned from `LogException`. There are multiple ways you can reliably avoid a deadlock. A simple way is `Task.Run(() => LogException()).Wait();`. This works because the task body runs without a synchronization context.

You also can add `ConfigureAwait(false)` inside of `LogException` but you cannot miss a single place. That makes this brittle.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not realize that .Wait() helped me avoid deadlocks.

Comment: It does not, what helps is the Run. Wait, Result and GetResult behave equally in terms of deadlocking.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change approach and implement own ExceptionLogger because it's ExceptionLogger job to log exceptions

> We provide two new user-replaceable services, IExceptionLogger and IExceptionHandler, to log and handle unhandled exceptions. The services are very similar, with two main differences:
>   We support registering multiple exception loggers but only a single exception handler.
>   Exception loggers always get called, even if we’re about to abort the connection. Exception handlers only get called when we’re still able to choose which response message to send.
>   Both services provide access to an exception context containing relevant information from the point where the exception was detected, particularly the HttpRequestMessage, the HttpRequestContext, the thrown exception and the exception source.

Here the sample code

```
public class ExceptionLogger : IExceptionLogger
{
    public virtual Task LogAsync(ExceptionLoggerContext context, 
                             CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {


    return MyLogger.Log(context, cancellationToken);
   }   
}
```